# Are there any effects of boiling copper immersion chiller with wort?

Tags: boil, off-flavor, wort-chiller

I’m contemplating the use of a copper immersion chiller.  Currently, doing partial batches, I’m able to cool my wort fairly quickly in an ice bath, then adding cooled water in the carboy.  I’d like to go to full boils, thus researching the use of a wort chiller.

I’ve seen some people add the IC to the wort boil, to sanitize it.  Are there any affects to the wort by doing this (eg – metallic taste)??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fine to boil the chiller for a few minutes to sanitize it. Just make sure you give the chiller a good cleaning in acetic acid prior to its first use, as per Palmer's [advice](http://www.howtobrew.com/section1/chapter2-2-2.html).

Answer (score 3):

Some people say that it's **better** to include the IC in your boil (if it's copper) as the copper gives off micronutrients (namely zinc) as well as providing a nucleation point which reduces the chance of boilovers.

See [Pennies in the Boil](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/2666/pennies-in-the-boil)